# Unable to install Laravel's 5 cashier/stripe packages

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I have put the "laravel/cashier": "~5.0" line in my composer.json file, updated it;

Next, I have put the line 'Laravel\Cashier\CashierServiceProvider' into $providers array in, app.php

Then, in cmd when I try to migrate table, php artisan cashier:table builder, i get the message:

[InvalidArgumentException] There are no commands defined in the "cashier" namespace.

Then, when I type: php artisan, there is no cashier:table command, what and where is the problem?

Comment: run `php artisan clear-compiled` and `composer dump-autoload` in the project's directory

Comment: @michael Still getting the same error message

Comment: @sk4yb3n did you have any luck getting this to work?

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem and when I run that commands `php artisan config:cache` and `php artisan clear-compiled` it worked...

Comment: Please use answers to post complete answers only and not comments. FYI, This was asked as a comment years back and the OP has replied no already.